# How to call Spotify API with Ajax / Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spotify

I'm sorry in advance for being a real beginner, but I really need to call this API for my school project and I don't know how to do it.
I need to get the Json from this API but I don't know how to get it. I want to have this type of info with my console.log :

```
{
  "albums": {
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases?country=FR&offset=5&limit=20",
    "items": [
      {
        "album_type": "album",
        "artists": [
          {
            "external_urls": {
              "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1OCpqnXexjxrakYtmur3rN"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1OCpqnXexjxrakYtmur3rN",
            "id": "1OCpqnXexjxrakYtmur3rN",
            "name": "Les Enfoirés",
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:1OCpqnXexjxrakYtmur3rN"
          }
```

I want to keep the lastest release and show it on my website.

```
var accessToken = "XXXXX";
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases',
    type: 'GET',
    data: 'name',
    headers {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

But I think my code is not good at all.
Here is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/12wx7m8c/

Have a nice day all,

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of typos, here's how it should be:

```
var accessToken = "XXXXX";
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases',
    type: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Also, right now you'll get a 401 Error back, because you need to replace the accessToken = "XXXX" line with the real access token you got from spotify.

EDIT: Here's how to get an access token https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/app-settings/

Comment: I will try to catch the right info to show it on my website now